# Is it possible to join two instances of the same RDDs

Tags: scala, mapreduce, bigdata, apache-spark

So, I have an RDD with key value pairs **(SecondName, FirstName)**. Let us call that **SecondNameFirstName**. Now I want to create **(FirstName, FirstName)** pairs for all the firstnames that goes with a surname. Would this join work?

```
SecondNameFirstName.join(SecondNameFirstName).map(x => x._2)
```

The idea is that after doing a join, I would have key value pairs of **(SecondName, (FirstName, FirstName))**. Now by only taking the second tuple, I would have key value pairs of **(FirstName, FirstName)**.

Comment: Could you use the 'apache-spark' tag? I normally correct it but I'm on a phone now

Answer (score 0):

Why go the trouble of joining the rdd? You could just map the initial rdd to the desired outcome:

```
val firstFirst= secondFirst.map{case (second, first) => (first, first)}
```

Comment: That is succint. Any idea how to do the same in python?